# how to scroll live cards in aglass activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview, google-gdk

I'm writing a glass app.

In one activity I want to scroll between few cards (which were popups in my android app).

1) I thought to use cardsScrollView.

**problem:** Is it possible to set customView to a card object?

2) I thought to use LiveCard

**problems:**

Is it possible to publish them inside my app and not in the timeline?

Is there an equivalent LiveCardsScrollView?

Any other idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

From Google's sample code at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/theme-widgets and API documentation at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView and https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollAdapter, it seems your 1) is possible, because:

1) The CardScrollAdapter's method `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` returns a View (not a Card);

2) CardScrollView's get methods also return a View or Object, not Card specifically;

3) You can replace `private List<Card> mCards;` in the sample code (link #1 above) with `private List<MyView> mViews;`

But the documentation at those links also use Card as example, and the word cards seem to refer to static cards. So will have to test to find out for sure. However, there's a statement in link #1 that says "You can build a standard view hierarchy yourself or use the Card class.", suggesting it's possible to use a custom view.

I'll get back with you within 12 hours after I test with my Glass tonight.

As for your question 2, the answer is yes - you publish the scrollable content inside your app and not in the timeline. You can launch the activity (as in the sample code in Google's link #1) from a menu item selection, and the menu is attached to your livecard. Then inside that scrolling view, you can only swipe left and right to see other cards (or maybe custom views) in the scrolling view, but not the timeline. You have to swipe down to exit the activity (immersion) to go back to livecard, then you can swipe left and right and see the timeline. Note the scrolling view is not like static cards and will never show in the timeline. Also note that inside the scrolling view, you may use GestureDetector to capture other gestures (besides swipe left and right and down).

---

Just confirmed: custom views can be added to CardScrollView! I used a view that extends FrameLayout and inflates a layout xml file, and added three such views to CardScrollView. It works nicely!

Also tried to add a custom view that does the Canvas drawing, but haven't been able to see it shown in the scrolling view. Will try more later.

---

Just tested and found you can add any views to the CardScrollView - I'm able to add 4 custom views to a scrollview: one static Card, one view with Canvas drawing, one with OpenGL ES 1.0 drawing, and the final one with OpenGL ES 2.0 drawing. This is good to know to me! Thanks for your question.

Comment: Has anyone tried using a CardScrollView with image views as the internal view and an image loaded to load the images?  I tried this with cards but had performance problems.